# Thunderbird Contact Sync to Ubuntu One

Tags: ubuntu-one, thunderbird, sync, contacts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Thunderbird Contacts sync with Ubuntu One](https://askubuntu.com/questions/101650/thunderbird-contacts-sync-with-ubuntu-one)

How can I synchronize Thunderbird contacts with Ubuntu one?

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible right now but it is being worked on.

You can find more details on [Mike Conley's Blog](http://mikeconley.ca/blog/2011/03/15/my-campaign-to-get-thunderbird-integrated-into-ubuntu-natty-narwhal-continues/).

Answer (score 1):

There's also a project that mostly works that will do this: https://launchpad.net/hedera