# How can I get Thunderbird Contacts to sync with Ubuntu One?

Tags: ubuntu-one, thunderbird, contacts

In the setup instructions for Ubuntu One with Thunderbird it reads:

Click on the checkbox next to "Directory Server" and select "Ubuntu One" from the pull down menu

Well, there is no Directory Server for U1 listed in my 11.10 install, what's missing?  Does Thunderbird need re-installing?  Or is it a U1 problem?

Answer (score 3):

### 11.10

Starting with Ubuntu 11.10, the default email application is Thunderbird. Ubuntu One contacts sync has integration with Thunderbird in Ubuntu 11.10.

The following instructions explain how to setup contacts sync in Ubuntu 11.10 with Thunderbird and use Ubuntu One contacts in Thunderbird.

**Setup contacts sync**

1. Open the Ubuntu One Control Panel
2. Click on the services tab
3. Click the "Install now" button
4. Enter your Ubuntu password when prompted
5. Click the "Install now" button under the "Enable Contacts Sync" section

**Copy contacts to Ubuntu One from Thunderbird**

6. Open Thunderbird
7. Click on the "Address Book" button
8. Click on the "Personal Address Book"
9. Select all the contacts you want to copy
10. While holding the "Ctrl" key, move the contacts from the "Personal Address Book" onto the "Ubuntu One" address book

**Auto-complete email address from the Ubuntu One address book**

11. Open Thunderbird
12. Click the "Edit" menu and select "Preferences"
13. Click on the "Composition" icon
14. Click on the "Addressing" tab
15. Click on the checkbox next to "Directory Server" and select "Ubuntu One" from the pull down menu
16. Click the "Close" button

[Source](https://one.ubuntu.com/help/tutorial/install-and-setup-contacts-sync/)

---

**Update**

I must admit I couldn't get it to work myself but after a bit of digging around I found that CouchDB address book intergration is not compatible with Thunderbird 9.0, unfortunately that's why you get no option to select Ubuntu One as a directory server - it relies on CouchDB!!

See below screenshot

[image]

Comment: This is the problem, under the last section "Auto-complete email address from the Ubuntu One address book" at point 5 there is no "Ubuntu One" to select in the "Directory Server".

Comment: have you followed the previous steps in the first section to set up contacts sync?

Comment: Yes, and my other U1 folders sync.  Even the step "Click the "Install now" button under the "Enable Contacts Sync" section" looks OK.

Comment: @Packwood I've updated the answer to include the reason why it's not working as expected. It may be fixed for Thunderbird 10 which is currently in development for 12.04.

Comment: @Packwood I've recently upgraded Thunderbird to 10.0.2 on Ubuntu 11.10 and the CouchDB addressbook intergration is now working, I can successfully integrate my Ubuntu One contacts with Thunderbird using the above steps.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Ubuntu One stopped syncing contacts in 2011 - so it [says](https://one.ubuntu.com/help/faq/why-is-contacts-sync-no-longer-active/) at the base of FAQ webpage, so I guess we can't sync with Thunderbird:

> As of June 1, 2011 the current Ubuntu One contacts sync for mobile will no longer be active. We also canceled development of syncing contacts with Thunderbird and Evolution.

Strange thing is that I just signed in to Ubuntu One from my Galaxy Nexus running Ubuntu, and it has synced my Ubutu One contacts to the phone.