# How to sync Ubuntu One Contacts with thunderbird?

Tags: ubuntu-one, 12.04, thunderbird

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Thunderbird Contacts sync with Ubuntu One](https://askubuntu.com/questions/101650/thunderbird-contacts-sync-with-ubuntu-one)

I'm testing Ubuntu 12.04 Beta 2. I can't find a way to sync my Ubuntu One contacts with thunderbird. Is it possible?

Comment: As far as I can tell, this is __not__ a duplicate: on Ubuntu 12.04 Beta, there is no sync contacts function to be found on Ubuntu One.

Comment: This https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/thunderbird-couchdb/+bug/977239 is a bug report I found on the issue - so far no answers on the subject

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu One contacts sync has integration with Thunderbird in Ubuntu 11.10. The following instructions explain how to setup contacts sync in Ubuntu 11.10 with Thunderbird and use Ubuntu One contacts in Thunderbird.

Setup contacts sync

Open the Ubuntu One Control Panel
Click on the services tab
Click the "Install now" button
Enter your Ubuntu password when prompted
Click the "Install now" button under the "Enable Contacts Sync" section
Copy contacts to Ubuntu One from Thunderbird

Open Thunderbird
Click on the "Address Book" button
Click on the "Personal Address Book"
Select all the contacts you want to copy
While holding the "Ctrl" key, move the contacts from the "Personal Address Book" onto the "Ubuntu One" address book
Auto-complete email address from the Ubuntu One address book

Open Thunderbird
Click the "Edit" menu and select "Preferences"
Click on the "Composition" icon
Click on the "Addressing" tab
Click on the checkbox next to "Directory Server" and select "Ubuntu One" from the pull down menu
Click the "Close" button

[Source](https://one.ubuntu.com/help/tutorial/install-and-setup-contacts-sync/)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I think you didn't read my post. It says I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 Beta 2.

12.04 ships with the new Ubuntu One client. There is no "Enable Contacts Sync" in the new Ubuntu One client. So this is not a duplicate at all. An I still can't get my contacts. Please reopen it an help me.