# Will Contacts ever sync with Thunderbird in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: sync, thunderbird, contacts

Status message says there is yet more disruption to this service.
Are Ubuntu actually serious about this service, or should we all just look for another provider?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get Thunderbird Contacts to sync with Ubuntu One?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/101650/how-can-i-get-thunderbird-contacts-to-sync-with-ubuntu-one)

Comment: And, lo, suddenly there it was, synced to Thunderbird, despite this message still being displayed on the Service Satatus page:Contacts
Syncing of contacts is no longer available in Ubuntu 12.04. Syncing contacts in other versions of Ubuntu is known to not work due to server issues. We are currently working on revamping the data sync infrastructure, with the server side component coming first, then clients.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can get (download) a .vcf file for the contacts (its called exporting contacts in most mailing services) from your contacts, open contacts, go to the menue bar, under tools you will find import. NOTE: this option may only load emails and names, leaving out phone or mobile numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Thunderbird (with Lightning calendar) and Zindus add-in for syncing contacts via Google.  It is seamless and reliable.

Evolution has it as standard but it does not sync data fields such as birthdays and anniversaries.